# My mythtv setup menus changed to greek, anybody else?

Tags: fonts, language-support, mythbuntu, mythtv

After the last update, my mythtv setup menus in the frontend and backend changed to greek, I think it is just a font issue because it looks like letter substitution rather than language.  Either way english is the language that is set everywhere I can find, and I can't find any greek font set anywhere.  Anybody else had a similiar issue?  Any idea how to fix it?

Mythbuntu 12.04, Mythtv 0.26

Comment: Have you checked the paths in `usr/share/mythtv/fonts`? Most are symlinks to `usr/share/fonts` and something in the upgrade may have changed or broken the link or pointed it to the wrong font.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks douggro, I looked for a broken/wrong link in the font dir but didn't find one,  was hoping someone knew which font the setup menus used.  I gave up checking evry font file and just reinstalled the msttf fonts and that seems to have solved it.